# access store from outside js file in nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm trying to access the store from a file outside a component
When I search for this problem I saw that people say that I should import the store from my file and then I can get access to it, but I can't make this work

my store is built like this:

```
const createStore = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    state: { ... },
    getters: { ... },
    mutations: { ... },
    actions: { ... },
  })
}
```

and I've tried to import it in my js file like I saw recommended

```
import store from '@/store'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You could import the store by registering it upon instantiation, like this:

External file `some-service.js`:

```
export default class SomeService {
  constructor(store) {
    this.store = store
  }
  doStuff() {
    this.store.dispatch('someAction')
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how the class is instansiated? Where does `store` originate from?